# Не работает передача переменной из ajax в php

Tags: javascript, php

Имеется следующий код:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test.php',
    data: option.stopImageNumber,
    success:function(data) 
    {
        alert(option.stopImageNumber);
    }
})
```

Переменная 'option.stopImageNumber' каждый раз генерирует рандомное число. При выполнении данного скрипта вывод результата из этой переменной успешно отображается в 'alert(option.stopImageNumber);', но при этом его не удаётся получить посредством PHP. Пожалуйста помогите получить число из этой переменной в PHP.

Comment: Что-то не видно php кода

Comment: $option = $_POST['data']; При использовании этого кода появляется ошибка: Warning: Undefined array key "data" in

Comment: потому что в ajax запросе у вас не указано, что `option.stopImageNumber` нужно передавать под ключом `data`. Соответственно в php вы и получаете такую ошибку

Comment: А как можно это указать?

Comment: @Вадим `.. data: { 'data': option.stopImageNumber }`

Comment: Warning: Undefined array key "data" in